# Google calendar integration with html static form on localhost

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a service account to create entries on a Google calendar. I'm really close on this.

I get the following errors when I let this run:

> Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in D:\wamp\www\calendar-test\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Signer\P12.php on line 54
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Unable to parse the p12 file. Is this a .p12 file? Is the password correct? OpenSSL error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line' in D:\wamp\www\calendar-test\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Signer\P12.php on line 56
>
> Google_Auth_Exception: Unable to parse the p12 file. Is this a .p12 file? Is the password correct? OpenSSL error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line in D:\wamp\www\calendar-test\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Signer\P12.php on line 56

```
    require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php";
    require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php";
    require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php";

    //obviously, insert your own credentials from the service account in the Google Developer's console
    $client_id = '1014261369752...........';
    $service_account_name = 'agentbranding@appspot.gserviceaccount.com';
    $key_file_location = 'google-api-php-client/agentbranding-..........p12';
    //echo $key_file_location;
    if (!strlen($service_account_name) || !strlen($key_file_location))
        echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Agent Branding Appointment");

    if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
    }
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name, 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/........6mp0df4@group.calendar.google.com/private/full/',
    $key)
    );
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $calendarService = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $calendarList = $calendarService->calendarList;

    //Set the Event data
    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
    $event->setSummary('Today Big Event');
    $event->setDescription('Big Event Dedcription');

    $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime('2016-02-17T17:00:00-07:00');
    $event->setStart($start);

    $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime('2016-02-18T17:00:00-07:00');
    $event->setEnd($end);

    $createdEvent = $calendarService->events->insert('$cal_id', $event);

    echo $createdEvent->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

If **google-api-php-client/agentbranding-..........p12** is the real file name (I mean the dots),I suggest

```
$key_file_location = dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client/agentbranding-..........p12';
```

Comment: But the error is still there. And this is the real file. Please help me to configure this calendar.

Comment: Thank you, the error log you have provided questions the validity of the "p12" certificate file. I have proposed one solution to address the location of the file. This should work if it's a Linux server (the forward slash),is it?

Comment: @MuhammadSohaib Still, **agentbranding-..........p12** does not look like a valid filename.

Comment: I have developed my own Google Calendar app, you can see it at http://postbrain.com ,http://postbrain.com/calendar .